# Send data between 2 iOS devices as quickly as possible

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, bluetooth, wifi

This is an "approach" question, rather than code.

I am looking to send data from one device, let's say an iPhone, to another device, probably an iPad, as quickly as possible. As in, I'd like an button pressed on the iphone to trigger and action on the ipad, as close to instantaneously as possible. (Both devices will be running my app at the time.)

I know I could send the data up to a cloud and then retrieve it, but I am looking for something much faster...is it possible to do this via a local wifi network or bluetooth, or is there another option?

Comment: Bluetooth can be configured ad-hoc (no user configuration necessary), but can take up to a minute. Wifi needs to be configured, but if both users are already configured it definitely offers faster transfer rates. If you're sending large files (>1MB), definitely WiFi. If it's smaller, you'll have to look at latency and setup/config times.

Comment: I am thinking that the initial set-up time is okay, but I'd like to be firing messages (short strings) from the iPhone to iPad, about every tenth of a second? Which would work better here?

Comment: This is a perfect use case for Bluetooth Low Energy (BT 4.0)